MockedStatic and the event loop - testing vertx verticles
I'm trying to test a verticle that looks like:
class PetShopVerticle extends AbstractVerticle {

    @Override
    public void start() {
        vertx.eventBus().<JsonObject>consumer(PET_SHOP_ADDRESS).handler(message -> {

            PetShopRetriever.getPetShopDetails(...)
                .onComplete(ar -> {
                    if (ar.succeeded()) {
                        ...
                    } else {
                        ...
                    }
                });

        });
    }
    
}

Where the event consumer in a verticle contains a static call: PetShopRetriever.getPetShopDetails(...).
And my unit test looks something like:
@ExtendWith({VertxExtension.class, MockitoExtension.class})
class PetShopVerticleTest {

    private Vertx vertx;

    private PetShopVerticle petShopVerticle = ...;

        private MockStatic<PetShopRetriever> staticMockPetShopRetriever;
   
    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() {

        vertx = Vertx.vertx();
        vertx.deployVerticle(petShopVerticle, handler -> {
            ...
        });

                staticMockPetShopRetriever = mockStatic(PetShopRetriever.class);
                staticMockPetShopRetriever.when(() -> PetShopRetriever.getPetShopDetails(...))
                    .thenReturn(Future.succeededFuture(getPetShopDetails()));

    }
        
        @AfterEach
        void tearDown() {
            staticMockPetShopRetriever.close();
        }

    @Test
    void staticMocksInEventConsumer() {
             vertx.eventBus().request(PET_SHOP_ADDRESS, getMessage(), handler -> {
                 assertTrue(handler.succeeded());
             });
    }

}

My issue is that because the static mock is initialized in the tests code, and meanwhile the consumer runs on the event loop thread pool, the static mock doesn't end up getting initialized on the same thread that actually runs the consumer... PetShopRetriever.getPetShopDetails(...) ends up not being mocked as desired.
Is there any way to initialize the static mock across all the threads in the event loop, so that when the consumer executes, it contains the mocked PetShopRetriever.getPetShopDetails(...) call?
Tried playing around with @RunTestOnContext
